# Beansheel sampler is not stopping after execution

Tags: java, jmeter

I am printing the responses in a csv file using beanshell sampler but it is not stopping after completion.

What can be done so that it stops after printing it. Below is the sample code I have used acctId is used in the pre processor from other thread group.

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.List;

char SEPARATOR = ',';

public void writeLine(FileWriter writer, String[] params, char separator)

{
   boolean firstParam = true;

   StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

   String param = "";
   for (int i = 0; i <params.length; i++)

   {

      param = params[i];

      log.info(param);

       if (!firstParam)

       {
               stringBuilder.append(separator);

       }

       stringBuilder.append(param);

       firstParam = false;

   }

   stringBuilder.append("\n");

   log.info(stringBuilder.toString());

   writer.append(stringBuilder.toString());

}

String csvFile = "D:/jmeter/test1/result.csv"; // for example '/User/Downloads/blabla.csv'

//String[] params = {"${acctId}", "${tranId}"};
String[] params = {"${acctId}"};

FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(csvFile, true);

writeLine(fileWriter, params, SEPARATOR);

fileWriter.flush();

fileWriter.close();
```

Comment: What behaviour are you seeing exactly? What do you mean by "stopping" ?

Comment: it keeps on executing and timer is not stopping in the right top corner. I have to manually stop it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "View Result Tree" Sampler or "Simple Data Writer" to save the response messages. Just click "Configure" and use save as XML and select "Save response data(XML)" with other required fields. Thought, it is not recommended for load test.

Comment: i dont want to show anything other than the variable value in the file and also i need to write multiple variables extracted at various threads groups all together in a single file, Simple Data Writer does not solve my problem. Any other help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way of saving a variable into a CSV file is using [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property

1. Add the next line to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   sample_variables=acctId
   ```
2. Restart JMeter to pick the property up
3. That's it now when you [run your JMeter test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) like:

   ```
   jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
   ```

   You will see an extra column in the `result.jtl` file holding the value of the `acctId` variable for each sampler.

---

Also be aware that [starting from JMeter 3.1 it is recommended to use Groovy for any form of scripting](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting). You will be able to replace your code with something like:

```
new File('D:/jmeter/test1/result.csv') << vars.get('acctId') << System.getProperty('line.separator')
```

If you don't like Groovy syntax be aware that you can use [FileUtils.writeStringToFile()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#writeStringToFile(java.io.File,%20java.lang.String,%20java.nio.charset.Charset,%20boolean)) function